# How to access a method in one class from other classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will parse some data in one class and then the parsed data will be inserted into sqlite DB ( and additional tasks) in other class.

I've created a sqlite class:

```
 class DB_MNG(object):

        def db_conn(self):

            self.conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
             self.cur.execute(
                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hosts(ip TEXT PRIMARY KEY 
                  UNIQUE, port INTEGER, details'
                    ' TEXT, details2 INTEGER)')

      def db_operator(self, ip, port, details, details2):
            self.ip = ip
            self.details = details
            self.port = port
            self.details2 = details2
            self.cur.execute('SELECT ip FROM hosts WHERE ip = ? ', 
            (self.ip,))
            self.raw = self.cur.fetchone()
            self.conn.commit()

    class data_parser(DB_MNG):
    def __init__(self):
    DB_MNG.__init__(self)
```

????????

some parsed data that I need to pass to the DB_MNG.db_opertaor and update the table accordingly...

Comment: Considering this is python, please take some time to indent your code properly as it can change the meaning of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Test1():
    def f1(self):
        print('Test1->f1()')

class Test2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj1 = Test1()
        self.obj1.f1()
```

First create class Test1, next in class Test2 I create object of Test1 class.

Then during create object from Test2 class you can run method from first class:

```
obj2 = Test2()
>> Test1->f1()
```